# Adding Multiple Images to UIPageViewController using Camera

Tags: swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uipageviewcontroller

new to app development.

What I want to do is allow the user to take 2 photos from the Camera and review them.  Will then code around those two photos.  Preference is just to take from Camera but also could be from PhotoLibrary.

My thought process around this was, click a button to take first photo, then display that photo in a `UIPageViewController` then allow them to take another photo by pushing a Button to call the camera again, then that Photo would be the second as part of the `UIPageViewController`. So the user can swipe with the 2 dots at the bottom to review, then select confirm.

So what I did was follow the `UIImagePickerController` to be able to allow the user to select from library or Camera and also implemented the `UIPageViewController`.  But having trouble putting the two together.

When I get an image from Camera I think I need to save it.  The pageviewcontroller gets the filenames from a NSMutableArray.

With the `viewDidLoad`... I call the Camera, and also the pageViewController.  My problem is the pageviewcontroller gets data from pageImages[] but how do I populate the array with the image name string?  Did I do it correctly below?  I think i may have a problem in that does the pageviewcontroller controller automatically update once i dismiss the picker otherwise will never get the image from the camera.  I am thinking i may have to call camera then pass the data to the view controller through segues?

Other thought I was having was to have a view controller that just displays the taken image, saves it, adds filename to array, then when user takes another photo, the image is saved and added to array and then passed through segue to the pageviewcontroller for the user to be able to scroll through both and either confirm or delete.  Thoughts?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createPhoto()

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotoPageViewControllerStoryBoard") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    var startVc = self.pageViewControllerAtIndex(0) as PhotoContentPageViewController
    var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVc)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -10, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-30)
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}



func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    var newImage: UIImage

    if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            newImage = possibleImage
    } else if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            newImage = possibleImage
    } else {
        return
    }

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        let imageName = NSUUID().UUIDString
        let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

        if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 80) {
            jpegData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
        }

        pageImages!.addObject(imageName)
  }


    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, think I got it, i changed the array to pass to the pageviewcontroller from the contentviewcontroller UIImages instead of filename strings.

Also, since the array was nil i didn't start the pageviewcontroller until after the first image was taken or chosen.

Off to battle the next set of code, to actually do something with the two image.  most likely will need some help in the future... near future. Thanks.